# Run script-block by trigger and specified branch

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I Have 2 branches in my project:

1. DEV
2. STAGE

Source code in STAGE branch, build by pipeline on commit in STAGE branch:

```
deploy-stage:
  only:
    - STAGE
  before_script:
    - some scripts for build...
  script:
    - some scripts for build...
```

Now i want to run script-block **only for DEV branch** and **only by call trigger with curl** [Like this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#triggering-a-pipeline)

How i can do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't limit your job exception by curl, I mean once you specified in your DEV stage that it is triggered by changes only on **DEV**, it will be runned if any changes are pushed to DEV Branch.

Instead, another approach is to use a condition based on a variable from your Curl and asserted in your stage example :

In your curl

```
curl --request POST \
  --form token=TOKEN \
  --form ref=dev\
  --form "variables[RUN_DEV_STAGE]=true" \  <===
  "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/9/trigger/pipeline"
```

And in your Gitlabci

```
deploy-dev:
  only:
    - dev
  script:
    - if [ -n "${RUN_DEV_STAGE}" ]; then continue else exit; fi
```